# Scrolling inside div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a code like this:

```
<div id="#wrap">
  <div class="overview">
    <div class="cnt">[...content...]</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both `.overview` and `.cnt` have their width set to about 10000px (via JS), while '#wrap' is set to `100%`. I set `overflow-x: hidden` to them, so scrollbars are hidden. But I want to scroll those divs left or right. So I created two `span` elements and some jQuery:

```
    var selec = $('.overview');

    $('span.largeNext').on('click', function() {
        selec.scrollLeft(100)
    })

    $('span.largePrev').on('click', function() {
        selec.scrollRight(200)
    })
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

**1** `scrollRight` does not exist. `scrollLeft` with negative number must be done to "scroll to the right"

**2** `jqelem.scrollLeft(position)` --> After more than one call to this, you may wonder why it will not scroll again. That's because it scrolls to that position, it doesn't increment the scroll to an offset. So `jqelem.scrollLeft(jqelem.scrollLeft() + offset)` is what you want to make it keep scrolling based on the current scroll value.

Here's a working example based on the code you posted:

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/6dsTU/

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="overview">
      <span class="largeNext"></span><span class="largePrev"></span>
      <div class="cnt">LOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLLLOLLLOLOLOLOLOLLOLLOLOLOLO</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
var selec = $('.cnt');

$('span.largeNext').on('click', function() {
    var currscrl = selec.scrollLeft();
    selec.scrollLeft(currscrl + 200);
})

$('span.largePrev').on('click', function() {
    var currscrl = selec.scrollLeft();
    selec.scrollLeft(currscrl - 200);
})
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.cnt
{

    overflow:hidden;

}
.wrap
{
   width: 10000px; 

}

.largeNext
{
   left:50px;
    top:50px;
    width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position:absolute;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

.largePrev
{
   left:0px;
    top:50px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   position:absolute;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```